# Use angular-snap into jhipster

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, snap.js

Hi i would like to use angular-snap into my j-hipster project.
I've installed it with bower in my project root, then I added the module in j-hipster app.js

```
angular.module('smeshApp', [....., 'snap']);
```

then i included in my index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-snap/angular-snap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/snapjs/snap.js"></script>
```

finally i tried to use the directive `snap-drawer` and `snap-content`
but doesn't work and also my j-hipster app doesn't work anymore.
where did I go wrong?

Comment: first of all you have an error you forgot to close the script tag,second do you get anything on your console?

Comment: @Mat. failed to instantiate module. this is thet strack trace Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module smeshApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'smeshApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: one more error in script tag you closed wrong <script/> its not the issue right?

Comment: @Mat. I Can't make angular snap work. I follow the tutorial here, https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js but the directive seems to be not read. Any idea on what i missed?